# table cell alignment with image and text

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

```
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
  <th>type</th>
  <th>descritpion</th> 
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td><p><img src="mail.ping" style="width: 30px;"></p>
  <span>type-cedit ad=nd debit and shopping</td>
 <td>description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

The above image is show table data. when image and text aligned inside table cell.
This works fine when text is smaller. but when text size is large. text is appearing below image.

In above image i need to make the 'shopping' work should come jus below 'type' if length is large. Text should not appear below image. how can i fix this alignment issue

Comment: td {padding;left: width of image} td img {margin-left: -??px width of image}

Comment: please add html code

Comment: @HirenVaghasiya can you please check above code..

Answer (score 0):

Applying `display:inline-block` or `float:left` you can align both

```css
.divin{
display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
  <th>type</th>
  <th>descritpion</th> 
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td><p class="divin"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="width: 30px;"></p>
 <span class="divin">type-cedit ad=nd debit and shopping</span></td>
 <td>description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```